# Use Google Maps API V2 without EVER having contacted Google's servers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Does anyone know of a way you can use Google's APIs without EVER having contacted Google's servers? Or has anyone been able to test this and know that it works?

I know that right now, the api has a requirement that it has to contact Google at least the first time, but we're trying to avoid even that.

Our use case is we want to use ONE mapping library where we can get Google's Public Maps (meaning we technically HAVE to use their apis to conform with the Terms of Service), but we need this mapping library to also still work when the app is only ever on a local network, never having public internet access.

Comment: "but we need this mapping library to also still work when the app is only ever on a local network, never having public internet access" -- since the Google Maps tiles are on Google's servers, I fail to see how you plan to accomplish this.

Comment: we want to still use the api, but we dont necessarily need google's public tiles. This way we can have one set of code that can show a map (not google) with never having internet, and the same set of code can also show google's public map when we have internet. In the case of no internet, we'd be hitting some local tile server serving something else

Answer (score 0):

Technically there are few ways to achieve that. On a local network you could make DNS point to your server for API key authentication and reply with "this key is OK" the way Google Play Services understand it. This might not work if GPServices check SSL certificate. On rooted devices you could also place a file that caches authentication result in private GPServices storage space.

Both are of course not as easy as exposing device to internet after installing the app, but may work for you if you have thousands of such devices.

Anyway I also suggest posting a feature request on gmaps-api-issues to allow the use of API v2 without having the key authenticated in case base tiles are not used.